# Getting a total count and sum using linq lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Code  Fruit

 A     Apple
 B     Apple
 C     Orange
```

And another that looks like this:

```
Code   Cost

 A       5
 B      10
 C       3
```

How can I turn this into a list with the total counts and sums?

To get a list that looks like this:

```
Fruit     Total Items    Total Cost

Apple         2              15
Orange        1              3
```

This is what I tried but it returns a duplicate list of apples. How can this be better written and done?

```
var totals = list1.Select(a => new totalsObject
{
    Fruit = a.Fruit,
    TotalItems = list2
        .Count(x => list1.Any(i => i.Code== x.Code && i.Fruit == a.Fruit)),
    TotalCost = list2
        .Where(x => list1.Any(i => i.Code== x.Code && i.Fruit == a.Fruit))
        .Sum(x => x.Cost)
})
.OrderBy(x => x.Fruit )
.ToList();
```

Comment: I know this comment is not an answer for your question, just a suggestion, but if it's possible and this data came from a DB, I ever suggest do this in a VIEW and don't work this at LINQ, improving the performance.

Comment: @MacGyver could you explain what you mean? If I get both of these sets of data. How would you do it in a view?

Comment: using a LINQ upon a SQL VIEW

Comment: @Leandro that makes sense. Thank you.This was retrieved from a database but via entity framework and I haven't looked into using views with EF.

Comment: No problem @user3266638 Actually I think is more easy work with a view as a "virtual table", so you can select it with linq directly, fast and pretty :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are projecting `list2` from `list1`. This is why you are getting the duplicates. Instead, you should join both lists and then group them:

```
var totals = list1
    .Join(list2, x => x.Code, x => x.Code, (a, b) => new { a.Fruit, b.Cost })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fruit)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Fruit = g.Key,
        TotalItems = g.Count(),
        TotalCost = g.Sum(x => x.Cost)
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Fruit)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

```
var query= from e2 in list2
           join e1 in list1 on e1.Fruit equals e2.Fruit
           group new{e1.Fruit, e2.Cost} by e1.Fruit into g
           orderby g.Key
           select new totalsObject 
                  {
                    Fruit = g.Key,
                    TotalItems = g.Count(),
                    TotalCost= g.Sum(e=>e.Cost)
                  };
```

Comment: I can't explain why you got downvoted. I suspect it's because I asked for a lambda solution and you did a query. But yours would have solved the question as well.